# React Native module AppRegistry

Tags: react-native

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Sahabat Koding Indonesia</Text>;
  }
}

const Bar = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Navigasi', () => Bar);
```

[image]

this is the error and the script screenshot

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Please edit your question to give us your code in text form instead of an image. That way we can help you much easier. Thank you.

Comment: Which React Native version do you own?